# How to update a div with an image in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, django-templates, django-views

The following is a matplotlib code that generates a scatter plot in as the response.

```
def plot(request):
    r = mlab.csv2rec('data.csv')
    fig = Figure(figsize=(6,6))          
    canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='gray')
    ax.scatter(r.x,r.y);       
    response=django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
    canvas.print_png(response)
    return response
```

I would like to update a div tag in the template using jquery ajax. Following is the jquery code that listens to a form sumbit button and updates a div on success.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function() { 
        $('#plot').submit(function() {
          jQuery.ajax({            
            url: this.action,
            timeout: 2000,
            aysnc: true,
            error: function() {
              console.log("Failed to submit");
            },
            success: function(r) { 
              $('#plotarea').html(r);
              }
          }) 
            return false;
          })
     })
</script>
```

But when I click the submit button, junk characters are displayed on the div instead of the image.

Could any body guide me on how I could display the image from the response ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing because `plot()` outputs the raw image data (with headers) and you assign it directly to the contentarea (`.html()`) of the div. When the url returns the image data directly it should be used as the `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag instead.

If you don't wish to redesign your workflow you could try base64 encoding the string and use this method: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

i.e. something like `$('#image').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + r);` in your success call.

Comment: I tried doing it. But I got the junk characters withing the div and I could see it only from Firebug.