# How to serve an image in Django using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, base64

I am trying to update a `div` element in my html page with a png image which gets returned from the Django server.

In my client-side script where I send an ajax POST request on a button click, I have -

```
    $('#mybtn').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/analysis",
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'data': $("#analysis_list").val(), csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value },
            success: function (response) {
                $('#imagediv').html('<img src=' + response + ' />');
            },
        });
    });
```

In my views.py, I have -

```
def analysis(request):
    dataFromClient = dict(request.POST)['data'][0]
    pathToImg = testAnalytics(dataFromClient)
    img = Image.open(pathToImg)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/png")
    img.save(response, "PNG")
    return response
```

Where `testAnalytics` method generates the image to be displayed according to the data sent by client and returns the path to it. `Image` is imported from `PIL`.

I am facing problem with rendering the image at client-side javascript. When I assign `response` to `src` attribute of the `<img>` tag, I see raw image data on the browser instead of the image (as discussed in here - [How to update a div with an image in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212486/how-to-update-a-div-with-an-image-in-django)). I am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have also tried base64 encoding on the response as follows (but not sure whether I have implemented correctly) -

```
success: function (response) {
                $('#imagediv').html('<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,' + response + '" />');
            }
```

I have referred to following links to get upto this point -
[Django: How to render image with a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981691/django-how-to-render-image-with-a-template)
[Serve a dynamically generated image with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074200/serve-a-dynamically-generated-image-with-django)

I am fairly new to web-programming as well as Django. Any insights regarding the problem will be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you returned it as base64, did you modify the img tag like this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1207190/870769

Comment: Yes. Although I did not refer to the same post you have mentioned, what I tried was similar to which they have discussed in there. I will edit my question with my code where I tried Base64 encoding.

Comment: also if you base64 at server would change content type

Comment: `$("#imagediv").html("<img src=" + URL.createObjectURL(response) + "/>");` ?

Comment: Tried it just now, didn't work. Earlier my `complete` method was also getting executed (I have an alert box there, suggesting my code reaches there); but with this my code doesn't reach there.

Comment: $("#imagediv").html("<img src=" + URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response], {"type":"image/png"})) + "/>"); ?

Comment: One step closer. The `complete` method gets executed, the raw image data is not there, but the image displayed is broken. Checked the actual .png file on the machine, opened fine.

Comment: `var reader = new FileReader(); reader.onload = function(e) {  $("#imagediv").html("<img src=" + e.target.result + "/>"); }; reader.readAsDataURL(response);` ?

Comment: Sadly, this didn't work either. Similar problem - `complete` method doesn't get executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try encoding the image using base64 before you send it.

```
import base64
#rest of your code 
with open("pathToImage.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Then

```
success: function(response){
            $('#imagediv').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + response + '" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want set image by content of any HTML tags you must apply `data:{type};{encode-format}` before image content and set `background` url in CSS, similar below:

```
html-element{
   background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAEklEQVQImWNgIAD+QzFuAeIAAPVzA/0vfQ+9AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) repeat;
}
```

Or set this by `src` attribute of `img` tag:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAEklEQVQImWNgIAD+QzFuAeIAAPVzA/0vfQ+9AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">
```

for example if you generate a new pattern in [www.patternify.com](http://www.patternify.com/) site, you can copy and use base64 content from **Base64 Code** field.